# sketching derivative of a graph

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I am wondering whether or not this is the right sketch of the derivative in the picture below:

[image]

UPDATE:

Here is the function as it appears in the question (please disregard the pencil marks):

[image]

Comment: It does not seem correct. The first red point ($x = -2$) indicates a minimum, but the black function does not have it.

Comment: It has the right sign and local min at the inflection you marked X, so looks OK. However it should be moved upward at the left red dot, since it seems $f$ is increasing there.

Comment: @coffeemath how do you mean moved upward? i thought f'(x) = 0 at X since it is an inflection point?

Comment: Inflection means $f''(c)=0$ not $f'(c)=0$. In the case of an inflection on the graph of $f(x)$ at $x=c$ there is either a local max or a local min at $x=c$ in the graph of $f'(x).$ (This is assuming your function has its first two derivatives everywhere where you want to do the derivative graph...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you position a set of axes directly below the given graph.  You then draw the graph of the derivative keeping in mind that the *slope* of the original function tells you the *value* of the derivative function.  Specifically, the marked points at $(-2,-5)$ and $(1,25)$ are points where the slope is zero. (Whether the slope is genuinely zero at $(-2,-5)$ is debatable but I believe that is the likely intent.)  You can project down to the $x$-axis on your new axes to obtains roots of the derivative.  However you draw the derivative, you *must* go through those two points.  Furthermore, you cannot cross at any other point.  I guess that gets you to here:

[image]

Now, you need to draw a graph that goes through those two dots and stays on the positive or negative side of the $x$-axis as indicated by the slope.  I guess the simplest graph that does that looks like so:

[image]

Comment: thanks! may I ask what software you used to generate these plots??

Comment: @dimebucker91 Mathematica.  Your function is $y=(-40/9)(x + 2)^2 (x - 1)$.  Once you know that, there are loads of software possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

The *height* of the graph $y = f'(x)$ at horizontal position $x_{0}$ represents the *slope* of the graph $y = f(x)$ at $x_{0}$.

Thus:

- If $y = f(x)$ "slopes upward (to the right)" at $x_{0}$, then the graph $y = f'(x)$ lies above the horizontal axis at $x_{0}$ (i.e., $f'(x_{0}) > 0$).
- If $y = f(x)$ "slopes downward (to the right)" at $x_{0}$, then the graph $y = f'(x)$ lies below the horizontal axis at $x_{0}$ (i.e., $f'(x_{0}) < 0$).
- If $y = f(x)$ has a horizontal tangent at $x_{0}$, then $y = f'(x)$ touches (and possibly crosses) the horizontal axis at $x_{0}$.

Since your graph $y = f(x)$ does not appear to have a horizontal tangent at the point $X = (-2, 5)$, the graph of the derivative is questionable near $x_{0} = -2$.

---

The *slope* of the graph $y = f'(x)$ at $x_{0}$ (i.e., the second derivative $f''(x_{0})$) represents the *concavity* of the graph $y = f(x)$ at $x_{0}$.

- If $y = f'(x)$ has a local extremum at $x_{0}$, then the concavity of $y = f(x)$ changes at $x_{0}$, i.e., the graph $y = f(x)$ has an inflection at $\bigl(x_{0}, f(x_{0})\bigr)$. (A graph can also have an inflection at a point with vertical tangent.)

The local maximum on your graph $y = f'(x)$ lies to the right of the point of maximum slope on $y = f(x)$, but this may be "an artifact of rendering". :)

**Disclaimer**: The fourth item, about inflection points, is intended to be applied only for functions appearing in a typical Calculus I course, e.g., for real-analytic functions.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the question as it appeared, I'm still a little confused about the inflection point, won't the slope of a graph always be zero at an inflection point? and that implies that f ' (x) has a root at that point?

Comment: An inflection point _can_ occur at a critical point, but need not: For every real number $k$, the polynomial $f(x) = kx + x^{3}$ has an inflection point at the origin, but $0$ is a critical point of $f$ if and only if $k = 0$. That said, in your book's graph, $-2$ does appear to be a critical point, so your red graph is qualitatively correct.